# How to start an intent from a linear layout on click inside a class extending fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a navigation drawer layout created from a NavigationDrawerFragment which extends fragment.I have added `android:clickable="true"` inside a linear layout in fragment_navigation_drawer as shown below.However i am stuck on how or where to add OnClick event in my NavigationDrawerFragment,or should i do it in another class which extends activity?Thanks in advance.

NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```js
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private View containerView;
    private AdapterClass adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new AdapterClass(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;


    }

    public static List<Information> getData() {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check};
        String[] titles = {"Make up", "Lotions", "Deodorants", "Gels"};

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {
            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);


            }

        };
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.snappy.stevekamau.snappy.NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:src="@drawable/header"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_clicked" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/basket"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:text="My Basket"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="Categories" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious approach is to explicitly set a `View.OnClickListener` on the relevant widget (i.e. in `onCreateView()`):

```
layout.findViewById(R.id.linear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(...);
    }
});
```

As far as your question goes:

> where to add OnClick event in my NavigationDrawerFragment,or should i do it in another class which extends activity?

The listener really belongs in the class that inflates the layout file. If that's your `NavigationDrawerFragment` (which appear to be the case), then that's where the listener should live. From there on you can propagate the call elsewhere, but you can [start an activity from a fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) just fine.

Comment: didn't `android:onClick` always look in the `Activity` for that method and not in the `Fragment`. Or did they change that?

Comment: @IvoBeckers: You may very well be right. I have to admit I never use that approach myself. However, the docs do say: "*Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. (...) For instance, if you specify `android:onClick="sayHello"`, you must declare a `public void sayHello(View v)` method of your context (**typically, your `Activity`**)*", which suggests to me that the mechanism can be used in *other* contexts too. I've updated my answer to no longer include the `android:onClick` option for now. Thanks.